# Is it okay to drive with tire damge like this?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

[image]

Not exactly sure what happened, parked my car and saw the damages on my car. Can someone clarify that it is okay to drive my car? All the tire shops are closed and I have work 7AM tomorrow morning.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is there any air leakage? How deep is the gouge? Are there any cords showing?

Comment: No air leakage, and no cords showing. The gouge is about an inch

Comment: An inch deep? I'd think if it were an inch deep it would be flat. I'd bet you mean the gash is an 1" along side. If so, could you tell me how *deep* it is?

Comment: Not exactly sure. But it does not look too deep. It is about 3/4 of a penny deep.

Comment: This looks like a Darwin Award contest if you drive with it.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend that you don't drive on that tyre. You've damage the sidewall, meaning there is an increased risk of a blowout, which could be very dangerous at speed.

I'd recommend you swap it for the spare, and get it changed after you leave work tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I would not drive your car till you get that tire replaced. you will have to replace it because a tire can't be fixed if the damage is on the side wall. you should put your spare tire on if you have one till you get another tire. I would have the wheel looked at also, the edge might be damaged. They should be able to do that when you get a new tire put on....hope that helped.